# image_view disparity_view stereo_view OSX

Tags: image-view

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**This post is not about asking a question but to document a workaround.

When running image_view/disparity_view/stereo_view tools in MacOSX. The program  opens an standard opencv window but shows a blank (black/white) image.  When you move the mouse cursor over the window, the cursor turns into a spinning wheel indicating the window is not responding.

Reason:
These programs use "cv::startWindowThread()" instead of "cv::waitkey()" to handle UI update. However, cv::startWindowThread  is not implemented in opencv highgui Carbon/Cocoa/QT backend which are typically used on OSX.

Workaround
Add cv::waitKey() to the main thread.
Here's the example for image_view.cpp

```
--- src/nodes/image_view.cpp    (revision 37880)
+++ src/nodes/image_view.cpp    (working copy) 
@@ -1,5 +1,6 @@  
   #include <ros/ros.h>  #include <nodelet/loader.h>
  +#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>    
   int main(int argc, char **argv)  { 
@@-15,7 +16,9 @@    my_argv.push_back("--shutdown-on-close"); // Internal
     manager.load(ros::this_node::getName(), "image_view/image", remappings, my_argv);
-
-  ros::spin();
+  while(ros::ok())
+  { 
+     cv::waitKey(5);
+  }    return 0;  }
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11934/image_view-disparity_view-stereo_view-osx/) by [tingfan](https://answers.ros.org/users/241/tingfan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 91 on 2011-11-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2011-11-15**:
Still, put a bug somewhere, so it gets fixed.

**Comment by [tingfan](https://answers.ros.org/users/241/tingfan/) on 2011-11-14**:
@Mac,  the ticket probably should go to opencv's track where the backend of startWindowThread should be implemented. However, I don't have enough knowledge right now how that could be done. So I decided to post a workaround here for now. Thanks for your input.

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2011-11-14**:
You should submit this as a ticket on the appropriate trac.

**Comment by [berkaydeniz](https://answers.ros.org/users/13836/berkaydeniz/) on 2014-03-25**:
This seems to be still a problem and I can not find any viable workaround. Proposed solution is okay for image_view library, any fix suggestions for camera_calibration?

**Comment by [deniz](https://answers.ros.org/users/13371/deniz/) on 2014-03-25**:
actually, you just need to replace rospy.spin with while not ros.is_shutdown(): cv.WaitKey(5) in cameracalibrator.py and cameracheck.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks for the report. As Mac said, please open a ticket (https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/newticket) so that the OpenCV devs fix this.

---

Originally posted by [Patrick Mihelich](https://answers.ros.org/users/180/patrick-mihelich/) with karma: 4336 on 2011-11-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0